# Cant ping a machine with2 NICs

Tags: networking, tcp, routes, ip, ping

There is a machine in the office with 2 NICS installed, a web server is running on it.

1st NIC) hardwired connection :

```
Connection specific DNS Suffix : nl.xxx.com
IP: 10.0.232.62
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway : 10.0.232.1
```

2nd NIC) Wireless network connecton

```
Connection specific DNS Suffix : nl.xxx.com
IP: 10.0.238.122
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 10.0.238.1
```

There is another machine with only one NIC which is connected to the same wireless network with the first machine.

```
Connection specific DNS Suffix : nl.xxx.com
IP: 10.0.238.92
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 10.0.238.1
```

I can not ping the first machine(web server) nor can I access the web server on port 80. The connection can not be established. This might be a routing problem because the first server has 2 NICs installed. When I disconnect the first server from hardwired connection, there is no problem. But the first machine needs to be connected to both 2 NICs.

Can you please help me how to solve this connectivity problem.

Both machines are Windows 7 machines.

ROUTE PRINT OUTPUT WHEN 2NICS CONNECTED

```
C:\Users\ozgen.gunay>route PRINT
===========================================================================
Interface List
 18...e8 94 f6 10 c5 87 ......TP-LINK N600 Wireless Dual Band USB Adapter
 11...bc 30 5b eb 3d 35 ......Broadcom NetXtreme 57xx Gigabit Controller
 20...00 50 56 c0 00 01 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
 22...00 50 56 c0 00 08 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 19...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
 21...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
 23...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #6
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.0.232.1      10.0.232.62     10
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.0.238.1     10.0.238.122     25
       10.0.232.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       10.0.232.62    266
      10.0.232.62  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.0.232.62    266
     10.0.232.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.0.232.62    266
       10.0.238.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      10.0.238.122    281
     10.0.238.122  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.0.238.122    281
     10.0.238.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.0.238.122    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
     192.168.17.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.17.1    276
     192.168.17.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.17.1    276
   192.168.17.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.17.1    276
    192.168.248.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.248.1    276
    192.168.248.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.248.1    276
  192.168.248.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.248.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.0.232.62    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.17.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.248.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      10.0.238.122    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.0.232.62    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.17.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.248.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.0.238.122    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 11    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 20    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 22    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 18    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 11    266 fe80::81b9:bd46:d647:e4d1/128
                                    On-link
 20    276 fe80::8cd1:1226:41e0:2004/128
                                    On-link
 18    281 fe80::b887:5d9e:22a4:18be/128
                                    On-link
 22    276 fe80::fc51:3127:e185:92a7/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 11    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
 20    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
 22    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
 18    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

ROUTE PRINT OUTPUT WHEN 1NIC CONNECTED

```
C:\Users\ozgen.gunay>route PRINT
===========================================================================
Interface List
 18...e8 94 f6 10 c5 87 ......TP-LINK N600 Wireless Dual Band USB Adapter
 20...00 50 56 c0 00 01 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
 22...00 50 56 c0 00 08 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 19...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
 21...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
 23...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #6
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.0.238.1     10.0.238.122     25
       10.0.238.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      10.0.238.122    281
     10.0.238.122  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.0.238.122    281
     10.0.238.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.0.238.122    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
     192.168.17.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.17.1    276
     192.168.17.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.17.1    276
   192.168.17.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.17.1    276
    192.168.248.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.248.1    276
    192.168.248.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.248.1    276
  192.168.248.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.248.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.17.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.248.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      10.0.238.122    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.17.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.248.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.0.238.122    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 20    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 22    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 18    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 20    276 fe80::8cd1:1226:41e0:2004/128
                                    On-link
 18    281 fe80::b887:5d9e:22a4:18be/128
                                    On-link
 22    276 fe80::fc51:3127:e185:92a7/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 20    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
 22    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
 18    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: What does output of `ip route` or `route -n` show on your machine with two nics ie. server? both times when 'wired connection is plugged in and not'

Comment: Hi @gabhijit , I added route output. Can you help me?

Comment: Looking at the routing table nothing surprising is observed - there's a `10.0.238.0/24` route, except I am not sure why there are two default routes, but that shouldn't as such be the cause for this problem. So still thinking, what does route table look like 'without the cable plugged in'?

Comment: Oh wait - from your client which address are you trying to connect to? or ping? is it `10.0.232.62` or `10.0.238.122`?

Comment: Hi @gabhijit , I try to connect from 10.0.238.92 to 10.0.238.122

Comment: Sorry totally clueless - nothing seems wrong here. Just to make sure? There's no windows firewall running right?

Comment: I added route output when 1 NIC connected. There is no firewall.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81970/discussion-between-gabhijit-and-ozgen).